# Response to be filtered and showed using pagination

Tags: java, jsp, pagination

I'm developing a sample application in Java where I'm using a key search for filtering data. My aim is to get the response and show only top 6 data in the first page followed by a next button to move forward or a pagination view. Please suggest a way to do that.[`My expected output screen is given below`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExWJo.png)

```
EmpDao dao = new EmpDao();
EmpBean ebn = new EmpBean();
ArrayList li = new ArrayList();

ebn = dao.select(ebn, lastname1,contact);
li = ebn.getLi();
request.setAttribute("res",li);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("tab1.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

Comment: If MySQL or PostgreSQL you can do this it seems: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to use Simple Pagination for this, it has all predefined method for display items,total items,page numbers, css style, onPageClick to display next records.

http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: ya i have download the flaviusmatis zip file but i doesn't know how to install inside the eclipse and set path in my jsp page  for pagnation can you help me.